# Problem on color mixing lamp on Proteus Arduino starter kit

Tags: pcb-design

I set the circuit and couldn't illuminate, where is the problem?

[image: my circuit on proteus]

[image: original arduino circuit]

Fritzing: https://fritzing.org/media/fritzing-repo/projects/c/color-mixing-lamp/images/Arduino%20Lamp%20Project.png

Comment: you have to run an appropriate sketch in the arduino

Comment: I thought my sketch was properly but there is a problem that rgb is not illuminating. i transferred hex code from arduino app, starterkit_basickit. on the book 9green 10red 11blue; a0red, a1green, a2blue, then i think set correctly.

Comment: what is the point of asking where the problem is, if you do not provide all of the available information ... determine where the problem occurs ... is it in reading LDRs or is it in lighting the LEDs? .... write a separate sketch to test each part

Comment: im not sure about the parts that i use. on arduino, parts were rgb led, 220 ohm resistor, 10k resistor, 3 photoresistor, 3 gel. i used 3 light dependent resistor for "3 photoresistor+3gel" is it correct? if it's correct, RGB should lit, but it doesnt. I'm new about using proteus and arduino. I just need to convert original arduino circuit to proteus. Here is the purpose: https://i.ibb.co/9yVtThk/image.png

Comment: just fixed by using TORCH LDR instead of normal ldr. FULLY WORKS.

Answer (score 1):

just fixed by using TORCH LDR instead of normal LDR. FULLY WORKS.